# Simplify selection ranges C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, range, solver

I've been working on the simplify selection ranges puzzle on codingame https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/simplify-selection-ranges and am completely stumped on how to get it done. Edit: I've just managed to get it to pass the first test, but all of the others are failing, here's test 4

> **Found:**  10-12
>
> **Expected:**  1-4,10,12,17-20

Any help/solutions would be appreciated 
https://pastebin.com/JP81NLLe

```
/**
 * Auto-generated code below aims at helping you parse
 * the standard input according to the problem statement.
 **/

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;


class Solution
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string N = Console.ReadLine();
        // Write an action using Console.WriteLine()
        // To debug: Console.Error.WriteLine("Debug messages...");
        //Removing the brackets at the start and the end of the string
        N = N?.Remove(0, 1);
        N = N?.Remove(N.Length - 1, 1);
        List<int> ints = new List<int>(Array.ConvertAll(N?.Split(','), int.Parse));
        List<int> finalI = new List<int>();
        string finalRanges = "";
        ints.Sort();
        List<string> intsString = ints.ConvertAll(s => s.ToString());
        int tripleC = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ints.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i + 1 < ints.Count && ints[i] + 1 == ints[i + 1])
            {
                tripleC++;
                finalI.Add(ints[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                if (tripleC > 1)
                {
                    // Add the one after as the previous one will fail for the end of the range, example: range is 5-7,previously would print 5,6 instead of 5,6,7
                    finalI.Add(ints[i]);
                    finalRanges += finalI[0] + "-" + finalI[finalI.Count - 1];
                    // Removing the ranges from the ints string list to add in the finalranges
                    intsString.RemoveRange(intsString.IndexOf(finalI[0].ToString()), finalI.Count);
                }

                if (finalRanges != "" && finalRanges[finalRanges.Length - 1] != ',')
                    finalRanges += ",";
                tripleC = 0;
                finalI.Clear();
            }
        }

        ints = intsString.ConvertAll(int.Parse);


        string[] ranges = finalRanges.Split(',');
        foreach (var str in ints)
        {
            Console.Error.Write(str + ",");
        }
        Console.Error.WriteLine(" ");
        int[] rangeInts;
        for (int i = 0; i < ranges.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            string s1 = ranges[i].Substring(0, ranges[i].IndexOf('-'));
            string s2 = ranges[i].Substring(ranges[i].IndexOf('-') + 1);
            Console.Error.WriteLine("s1 {0} s2 {1}", s1, s2);
            rangeInts = new[]
            {
                    // Finding the first and second number by substringing the start to before the hyphen, then after the hypen to the end to find the two numbers
                    int.Parse(s1),
                    int.Parse(s2),
                };
            for (int j = 0; j < ints.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                if (ints[j] < rangeInts[0] && ints[j + 1] > rangeInts[1])
                {
                    //insert the range in between the two values it's closest too, adding i as the intsString will be
                    // a different length to the ints so they will get put in a row without it
                    intsString.Insert(j + 1 + i, ranges[i]);
                    Console.Error.WriteLine(intsString[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < intsString.Count; i++)
        {
            string s = intsString[i];
            if (i < intsString.Count - 1) s += ",";
            Console.Write(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's a game, play with it!

Comment: I've spent over 10 hours on it already :(

Comment: Debugger is your friend. Did you consult it?

Answer (score 0):

I had a bit of time and I've tried it, but you must do yourself, trying to debug messages and so. A fast implementation, not the best:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

/**
 * Auto-generated code below aims at helping you parse
 * the standard input according to the problem statement.
 **/
class Solution
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string N = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Error.WriteLine(N);
        // Write an action using Console.WriteLine()
        // To debug: Console.Error.WriteLine("Debug messages...");
        int[] array = N.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s.Trim())).OrderBy(n => n).ToArray();

        int lastNum = 0;
        int rangeLength = 0;
        string result = "";
        string bufferResult = "";
        int currentNum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= array.Length; i++) {
            bool flush = false;
            if (i < array.Length) {
                currentNum = array[i];
                if (lastNum == 0) {
                    lastNum = currentNum;
                    rangeLength = 0;
                    bufferResult = "" + lastNum;
                }
                else if (lastNum + 1 == currentNum) {
                    lastNum = currentNum;
                    rangeLength++;
                    bufferResult += "," + lastNum;
                }
                else {
                    flush = true;
                }
            }
            else {
                flush = true;
            }
            if (flush) {
                // Flush
                if (result.Length > 0) {
                    result += ",";
                }
                if (rangeLength > 1) {
                    result += string.Format("{0}-{1}", (lastNum - rangeLength), lastNum);
                }
                else {
                    result += bufferResult;
                }
                lastNum = currentNum;
                bufferResult = "" + lastNum;
                rangeLength = 0;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just managed to finish it before seeing your response! I will have a look through yours and seee what I can do better as mine's a complete cluster atm. Thank you for your time, I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry, I can't validate your code. If my code passes all tests the thread is over, check it as response, or upvote it! If you want to better your code, perhaps start again from 0. The goal is that you learn programming, try it with my code, or fix yours.

Answer (score 0):

Split the problem in two parts which makes it simpler as well.

Myself i would create a class which represents a range for the result.

```
public class Range
{
    public Range(int num)
    {
        Left = Right = num;
    }

    public int Left { get; set; }

    public int Right { get; set; }

    public bool IsAdjecentRight(int num)
    {
        return num == Right+1;
    }

    public bool TryAddRight(int num)
    {
        if (!IsAdjecentRight(num)) return false;
        Right = num;
        return true;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (Left == Right) return $"{Left}";
        if (Left == Right - 1) return $"{Left},{Right}";
        return $"{Left}-{Right}";
    }
}
```

The main method of the solution will become much simpler this way:

```
class Solution
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string N = Console.ReadLine();

        var nums = N.TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']').Split(',').Select(x => byte.Parse(x)).OrderBy(x => x);

        List<Range> ranges = new List<Range>();
        Range r = null;
        foreach (var num in nums)
        {
            if (ranges.Count == 0)
            {
                r = new Range(num);
                ranges.Add(r);
                continue;
            }
            if (r.TryAddRight(num)) continue;

            r = new Range(num);
            ranges.Add(r);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", ranges));
    }
}
```

Comment: lol only noticed this is an old question.... silly me. At least i had fun with the problem ;P